# Is it necessary to normalize pixel values if there are only black and white ones (no greys)?

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, grayscale, resnet

Is it necessary to normalize pixel values if there are only black and white ones (nothing in between/no greys), before feeding into ResNet18 for classification?

IOW, is this transform necessary?

transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])

Note: I'm currently stacking each black and white image 3 times so it aligns with ResNet's RGB expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the model is trained expecting values with 0 mean and some measured variance.

Thinking about your case, you would getting something like, eg,
blue channel pixel with 1:

(1-0.485)/0.229 = 2.24

and for pixel with 0:

(0-0.485)/0.229 = -2.11

If you are using pre trained weights i would guess that yes, it is necessary, otherwise, you can measure it in your training accuracy.
Anyway, if you are not sure, test the result with and without it.